# Add data to ArrayList only if the key exists

Tags: java, android, json, key

I want to add the JSON data to the `ArrayList`. The JSON data is not consistent, all of the objects don't have same keys. Here's example:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "option1": "option 1",
            "option2": "option 2",
            "option3": "option 3",
            "option4": "option 4"
        },
        {
            "title": "title 2",
            "option1": "option 1"
        },
        {
            "title": "title 3",
            "option1": "option 1",
            "option2": "option 2"
        }

    ]
}
```

**Question:**

I declared all keys as nulled and if it has the key value then i add it, otherwise adds null value. However I think it can be done in a better way that i should not add the keys with null values, should add the key if it has a value.

**Here's my code:**

```
List<listItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);

    String titleStr, optionStr1, optionStr2, optionStr3, optionStr4;
    titleStr = optionStr1 = optionStr2 = optionStr3 = optionStr4 = null;

    if ( item.has("title") ) {
        titleStr = item.getString("title");
    }

    if ( item.has("option1") ) {
        optionStr1 = item.getString("option1");
    }

    if ( item.has("option2") ) {
        optionStr2 = item.getString("option2");
    }

    if ( item.has("option3") ) {
        optionStr3 = item.getString("option3");
    }

    if ( item.has("option4") ) {
        optionStr4 = item.getString("option4");
    }

    items.add(new listItem(
            titleStr,
            optionStr1,
            optionStr2,
            optionStr3,
            optionStr4
    ));
}
```

**Edit:** To make it clear, my question is that do I need to enter the NULL values to the ArrayList for the keys that do not exist? or can I skip such keys?

For example the first item has option1, option2, option3 and option4 while the second item has only option1 but in my case I am still adding the option2=null, option3=null and option4=null. Can I only add option1 for this item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a method for this:

```
public String getIfNotNull(JSONObject item, String name){
   return item.has(name)?item.getString(name):null;
}
```

and run it with

```
items.add(new listItem(
   getIfNotNull("title"),
   getIfNotNull("option1"),
   getIfNotNull("option2"),
   getIfNotNull("option3"),
   getIfNotNull("option4")
));
```

The `?` operator is a short form of:

```
if(item.has(name)){
    return item.getString(name);
}else{
    return null;
}
```

If the condition begore the `?` is `true`, it will return the result of the expression after the `?`, else the result of the expression after the `:`.

By the way, class names (like `listItem`) should start with an uppercase letter by convention (at least in Java)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm really beginner, so maybe I'm not understanding correctly. My question is that do I really need to enter the null values for the keys that do not exist? (for example for second item, it has only option1), and in this case it will be still adding option2, option3, option4 with null values. is this the way to do?

Comment: If the constructor of `listItem` requires them, you need the values but you can overload the constructor that not every item is needed.